# Live Reloading после загрузки файлов

Tags: angular5

Есть инпут для загрузки картинок, загружаю на сервер с помощю multer. После загрузки перемещаю файлы в **src/assets** , и сразу срабатывает Live Reloading, а мне надо полученый массив отрисовать, не пойму как исправить!

```js
onFileSelected(event){
    const formData = new FormData();
    for (const element of event.target.files) {
      formData.append('image', element);
    }

    this.adminService.loadImages(formData)
      .pipe(takeUntil(this.unsubscribe))
      .subscribe(
        images => this.images.push(images),
        error => console.log(error)
      );
  }
```

```html
<input  placeholder="Загрузка картинок"
                  formControlName="images"
                  type="file"
                  multiple
                  accept="image/*"
                  (change)="onFileSelected($event)"
          >
```

Comment: Эм.. Тут всё не так...

Comment: ?? так напишите как надо

Comment: Во-первых, что вообще dev-сервер делает на проде? Во-вторых, что там делают исходники? И в-третьих, что загружаемые файлы делают в папке с кодом?

Comment: Ето не прод, и файлы пока временно там лежат для удобства!

Comment: сё равно файлам там делать нечего.